# enabling tomcat web apps to be served from Ubuntu lucid

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, firewall

I have tomcat running on 8080 on a ubuntu lucid server. I am able to access it fro local machine. However I am unable to access the tomcat from any machine outside.
Is it due to firewall restrictions.
WHat do I need to do to enable accessing tomcat from remote machines.
Tried adding this rule to iptables but it did not solve
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --protocol tcp --destination-port 80 \
    --in-interface eth0 --jump REDIRECT --to-port 8080

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Bala Thiruppanambakkam

Answer (score 6):

Your iptables command only redirects requests from 8080 to 80. But if you have default policy which is deny, this might not be enough.

Here is the copy/paste from a working Tomcat server iptables script:

```
# this allows incoming packets to port 80
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# same as above but for 8080
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
# this redirects all traffic coming to port 80 into 8080
/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Could you accept the answer then? That's what stackoverflow is all about.